# tf.summary.image seems not work for estimator prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I want visualize my input image use tf.estimator when predict, but it seems tf.summary.image not save image. But it work for training.

This is my code in model_fn:

```
...
summary_hook = tf.train.SummarySaverHook(
        save_secs=2,
        output_dir='summary',
        scaffold=tf.train.Scaffold(summary_op=tf.summary.merge_all()))
        #summary_op=tf.summary.merge_all())
tf.summary.histogram("logit",logits)
tf.summary.image('feat', feat)
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions=preds, prediction_hooks=[summary_hook])
...
```

and this my prediction code:

```
config = tf.estimator.RunConfig(save_summary_steps=0)
estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn, model_dir='logs', config=config)
preds = estimator.predict(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
```

Is there something wrong for using `tf.train.SummarySaverHook`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that you need to put the summary ops (histogram/image) *before* calling `merge_all` so that `merge_all` actually has something to merge.

```
...
tf.summary.histogram("logit",logits)
tf.summary.image('feat', feat)
summary_hook = tf.train.SummarySaverHook(
    save_secs=2,
    output_dir='summary',
    scaffold=tf.train.Scaffold(summary_op=tf.summary.merge_all()))
    #summary_op=tf.summary.merge_all())
if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions=preds, prediction_hooks=[summary_hook])
...
```